# How to ask questions during connectivity issues?

Tags: support

After a few hours of not being able to reach meta.mathoverflow.net,
(possibly due to DNS?), I resorted to asking a question about it on the
main site.  Later I posted something to a chat room, and during that
time the connectivity issue seemed to resolve.  (Also during that time,
I had problems commenting, editing and deleting the question I asked.
I have since deleted that question.)

If this recurs, should I try chatroom for MathOverflow?  Is there a better
resource to try on the stackexchange network?

Comment: The MO moderators have an email address moderators"at"MO.net with MO expanded in the obvious way. If however it is *purely* techncical matter related to the site to contact SE seems more reasonable. Here you could try http://meta.stackoverflow.com if this worked or see here for email http://stackexchange.com/about/contact though I do not know if this is intended for such things, too, but it seems so.

Comment: You can also use http://isup.me/ to check if it is just you or also others (i.e. is it your problem or their problem). Also if there is some serious issue there will be a post on [Meta.SE] about it, so look around.